# Does the JVM serialize calls to JNI_OnLoad and JNI_OnUnload?

Tags: multithreading, java-native-interface, thread-safety

Suppose I have a C library (libcurl or opens, say) that requires an initialization function that is not thread-safe.  I can initialize it in `JNI_OnLoad` but I could potentially race against other JNI libraries that call the initialization function.  Does the JVM guarantee that this can't happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, JVM does not have a mutex for calling **JNI_OnLoad** for different native libraries.

On the other hand, JVM does guarantee that **JNI_OnLoad** will be called only once, so if more than one thread of your Java code **loadLibrary()** for the same library, then there will be no race problems.

Comment: Got it.  So it seems like my problem is not solvable.

Comment: I am afraid the problem is deeper than that. I read the doc, ***This function is not thread safe.** You must not call it when any other thread in the program (i.e. a thread sharing the same memory) is running. This doesn't just mean no other thread that is using libcurl. Because `curl_global_init` calls functions of other libraries that are similarly thread unsafe, it could conflict with any other thread that uses these other libraries.*

Comment: @AlexChon Does that mean that I cannot use libcurl from Java, unless I write a custom launcher?

Comment: @AlexChon My current plan is to use my own libcurl and associated libraries (copied from the system versions at program launch).

Comment: Through the **curl** documents, I don't see any mention of system library race conditions. I am sure that if your Java process loads **libcurl** from different threads, the risks are higher. But the remark that I cited above, and the code of the `curl_global_init` function show that the concerns are much wider (or deeper, if you prefer). AFAIK, most of **curl** functionality can be done in native Java, without the library. If you really need it, keep in mind that a typical JVM is multithreaded long before your code starts to run, and if the remark is relevant for your system, you are screwed.

Comment: To be on the safe side, you can choose to run **curl** command from your Java code via **Runtime.exec()**, or you can write your own [Java wrapper](https://www.developer.com/java/data/how-to-create-a-jvm-instance-in-jni.html) in C. It can load **libcurl** even without **dlopen()**, initialize it on the main thread while it is still the only one, and after that start the JVM.

Comment: I think that I will instead require that libcurl be linked against OpenSSL 1.1+ or BoringSSL.  Those initialize automatically and thread-safely.  I can tell the JVM to initialize Winsock.  So the only thing I need to worry about is libcurl initialization itself, and I can deal with that.